# How to groupby and sum values of only one column based on value of another column

Tags: pandas, groupby

I have a dataset that has the following columns: Category, Product, Launch_Year, and columns named 2010, 2011 and 2012. These 13 columns contain sales of the product in that year. The goal is to create another column Launch_Sum that calculates the sum of the **Category** (not the Product) for each Launch_Year:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'Category':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
    'Product':['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
    'Launch_Year':[2010,2012,2010,2012,2010,2011],
    '2010':[25,0,27,0,10,0],
    '2011':[50,0,5,0,20,39],
    '2012':[30,40,44,20,30,42]
)}
```

| Category | Product | Launch_Year | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | Launch_Sum (to be created) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | item1 | 2010 | 25 | 50 | 30 | 52 |
| A | item2 | 2012 | 0 | 0 | 40 | 114 |
| A | item3 | 2010 | 27 | 5 | 44 | 52 |
| B | item4 | 2012 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 92 |
| B | item5 | 2010 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 10 |
| B | item6 | 2011 | 0 | 39 | 42 | 59 |

I did a groupby and sum, which does *have* the result I want (shown in **bold** in the table below), but I don't know how to pull out the specific result and assign it to a new column in the original dataset:

```
df.groupby(['Category']).sum()
```

|  | Launch_Year | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category |  |  |  |  |
| A | 6032 | **52** | 55 | **114** |
| B | 6032 | **10** | **59** | **92** |

Sorry, I don't know how to show a groupby object in markdown, hope the table above still makes sense. The Launch_Year sums are irrelevant. The required sums are all there under the year columns. How do I get these sum values and assign them to the rows with corresponding Category and Launch_Year? I need to be able to do this effectively for a large (>5000) number of categories and the year sales columns from 2010 to 2022.

Answer (score 1):

I figured a way to do it, but it doesn't look efficient at all. Regardless, the following code got me the results I needed.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'Category':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
    'Product':['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
    'Launch_Year':[2010,2012,2010,2012,2010,2011],
    '2010':[25,0,27,0,10,0],
    '2011':[50,0,5,0,20,39],
    '2012':[30,40,44,20,30,42]
)}

test_grouped = test.groupby(['Category']).sum()
test_grouped.reset_index(inplace=True)

for cat in test_grouped.Category:
    for year in test.Launch_Year.unique():
        test.loc[((test.Category == cat) & (test.Launch_Year == year)), 'Annual_Sum'] = test_grouped[test_grouped.Category == cat][str(year)].values[0]
```